# Create "netbootmachinefilepath" Active Directory Computer Attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to update the `netbootmachinefilepath` attribute after clearing it.
Because this attribute can be either non blank or deleted, I need to create it again after the value has been "cleared" because "clearing" it actually deletes it.

How can I recreate this attribute using Powershell?

I was hoping there would be something like

```
$directoryEntry.Properties.Create("netbootmachinefilepath")
$directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
```

**EDIT** Due to software issues on our servers I'm not able to use the ActiveDirectory module.

Comment: Please show some more (code) context. What value is assigned to `$directoryEntry`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work no matter the attribute has or does not have a value before.

```
$directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"].Value = "yourvalue"
$directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
```

Even `$directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath")` is false
`$directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"]` will never return null. It return an empty `PropertyValueCollection`.

**Tested the code above and it successfully set the value, even it has no value before.**

Comment: That doesn't work because the netbootmachinefilepath does not exist once it has been cleared.

Comment: I can confirm this because $directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") is equal to false.

Comment: Yes,  `$directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath")` return `false`, but `$directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"]` will still return a `PropertyValueCollection` that you can use to set the value.

Comment: oh really? Then why does $directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") return false?

Comment: Probably because its value is empty.

Comment: Checked the source code of `public PropertyCollection.PropertyValueCollection this[string propertyName]` (using reflector). Unless `propertyName` is null (throw exception), it will always return `PropertyValueCollection`. Even `$directoryEntry.Properties["@#$%^"]` will return a `PropertyValueCollection`.

Comment: baldpate you are right. I incorrectly assumed that $directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") returning false meant that it would be impossible to set it since I assumed that meant it doesn't exist.